# How to add an un-managed beta package to my partner community

Tags: unmanaged-package

I have uploaded an unmanaged beta package in our partner org.  Why doesn't it show up under the packages tab of our partner community?  There are no packages under that tab, just a diagram about managed and unmanaged packages. Our organization is "connected/Linked" in the partner community. Here's the confirmation of the upload: confirm
"Upload Complete
Your package is now available for install using the installation URL below. To publish on AppExchange, log on with your publisher login to access your public listings."

Comment: Have you linked the dev org to the publishing org?

Comment: Yes,  it appears under the organization tab.  And when I try to connect, I get the message: Please correct the following error(s):

    The Organization specified is already linked to this Partner.